# Error code 706 when signing PDF using Web Agent in Java

Tags: cosign-api

When testing the Web Agent sample in Java, I am getting an error reply

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="error">
  <Error>
    <returnCode>706</returnCode>
    <errorMessage>Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s</errorMessage>
  </Error>
</response>
```

I followed the Ruby example in the CoSign Web Agent samples and the [documentation](http://docs.arx.com/CoSign_APIs/doc_v7.1/Default.htm#doc_7.1/Request%20Format.htm)

I have used the **demo.pdf** file provided in the sample.

This is the XML (from [test app](http://webagentdev.arx.com:88/testApp/)) sent in the POST request (the `<content></content>` has the Base64 encoded PDF, but omitted because of length).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<request>
  <Logic>
    <allowAdHoc>true</allowAdHoc>
    <workingMode>pull</workingMode>
    <enforceReason>false</enforceReason>
  </Logic>
  <Url>
    <finishURL>http://localhost:64956/retrieveSignedFile.aspx</finishURL>
  </Url>
  <Document>
    <fileID>1234567890</fileID>
    <contentType>pdf</contentType>
    <content>{BASE64 encoded pdf content}</content>
  </Document>
</request>
```

The following is the java code I have used:

```
public class CoSignTest {
    private static final String INPUT = "D:\\tmp\\demo.pdf";
    private static final String PRECONTENT = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n" +
            "<request>\n" +
            "  <Logic>\n" +
            "    <allowAdHoc>true</allowAdHoc>\n" +
            "    <workingMode>pull</workingMode>\n" +
            "    <enforceReason>false</enforceReason>\n" +
            "  </Logic>\n" +
            "  <Url>\n" +
            "    <finishURL>http://localhost:64956/retrieveSignedFile.aspx</finishURL>\n" +
            "  </Url>\n" +
            "  <Document>\n" +
            "    <fileID>1234567890</fileID>\n" +
            "    <contentType>pdf</contentType>\n" +
            "    <content>";
    private static final String POSTCONTENT = "</content>\n" +
            "  </Document>\n" +
            "</request>";
    private static final String POST_URL = "https://webagentdev.arx.com/Sign/UploadFileToSign";
    private static final String PULL_URL = "https://webagentdev.arx.com/Sign/DownloadSignedFileG";
    public static final int TIMEOUT = 300000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(INPUT);
        String content = PRECONTENT + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(loadResource(is)), "UTF-8") + POSTCONTENT;
        System.out.println(content);
        String reply = new String(sendDocForProcessing(URLEncoder.encode(content, "UTF-8")));
        System.out.println(reply);
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

    private static String sendDocForProcessing(String content) throws Exception {
        HttpClient client = null;
        HttpMethodBase method = null;
        SimpleHttpConnectionManager mgr = new SimpleHttpConnectionManager();
        String reply = "";
        try {
            mgr.getParams().setConnectionTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            mgr.getParams().setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            client = new HttpClient(mgr);
            method = new PostMethod(POST_URL);
            method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(1, false));
            method.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", TIMEOUT);
            client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
            method.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            method.getParams().setParameter("inputXML", content);
            client.executeMethod(method);
            reply = new String(method.getResponseBody());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(method != null) {
                method.releaseConnection();
            }
            client = null;
            mgr.shutdown();
        }
        if (isSigningSuccessful(reply)) {
            return reply;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Failed in signing the document. Error: " + reply);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isSigningSuccessful(String reply) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(reply.getBytes()));
        Element elem = doc.getDocumentElement();
        String type = elem.getAttribute("type");
        return !"error".equals(type);
    }


    public static byte[] loadResource(InputStream in) {
        if (in == null) {
            return new byte[0];
        }
        try {
            int indice, tempIndice;
            byte[] tempArr;
            byte[] mainArr = new byte[0];
            byte[] byteArr = new byte[65535];
            for (indice = 0; (indice = in.read(byteArr)) > 0;) {
                tempIndice = mainArr.length + indice;
                tempArr = new byte[tempIndice];
                System.arraycopy(mainArr, 0, tempArr, 0, mainArr.length);
                System.arraycopy(byteArr, 0, tempArr, mainArr.length, indice);
                mainArr = tempArr;
            }
            in.close();
            return mainArr;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the XML that you sent ***to*** the Web Agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for adding your Java code. Note that the `HttpClient` instance is configured incorrectly and as a result the http-post request is sent empty. Take a look at the modifications I did in your `sendDocForProcessing` function in order to properly post the XML content:

```
private static String sendDocForProcessing(String content) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = null;
    PostMethod method = null;
    String reply = "";
    try {
        client = new HttpClient();
        method = new PostMethod(POST_URL);
        method.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        NameValuePair[] data = { new NameValuePair("inputXML", content) };
        method.setRequestBody(data);
        client.executeMethod(method);
        reply = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(method != null) {
            method.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
    if (isSigningSuccessful(reply)) {
        return reply;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Failed in signing the document. Error: " + reply);
    }
}
```

The content passed to the above function should not be URL-encoded as it is already done by the `HttpClient` library.

In addition, when analyzing the response, I suggest you to check the value of the `returnCode` element rather than the `type` property. The response is always of type 'error'.
Also note that the function name `isSigningSuccessful` is misleading as this stage is still prior to the act of signing.

Answer (score 1):

The XML elements are case sensitive and must be passed as shown in the [documentation](http://docs.arx.com/CoSign_APIs/doc_v7.1/Default.htm#doc_7.1/Request%20Format.htm#FileUploadSignatureInitiationReqParams) (e.g. `Document` instead of `document`, `Auth` instead of `auth` and so on). In addition, your XML request is missing the `finishURL` parameter which is mandatory.

Also note that some parameters in your XML request are obsolete. See the updated request parameter list in the link above. A sample XML is available [here](http://docs.arx.com/CoSign_APIs/doc_v7.1/Default.htm#doc_7.1/Sample%20XML%20Request.htm#SignRequestXMLsample).

Comment: Almog

Even after changing the request XML, the response is the same. The request XML has been updates in the question.

Comment: Here is a useful application to test your XML requests - http://webagentdev.arx.com:88/testApp/

Comment: Your XML request seems to be fine. Make sure to URL-encode your XML before posting the request.

Comment: Almog, getting the error even after URLEncoding the XML.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Can you please post a new question with your Java code?

Comment: @ Almog G, I have updated the question with the Java code I have used to test and also changed the POST xml to the bare minimum mentioned in the Ad-hoc example on http://webagentdev.arx.com:88/testApp/